# Disconnected.You are now offline

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I turned off my computer accidentally while updating Ubuntu 14.O4 and now WiFi is not working when I connect it I'm getting this message:

`Disconnected.You are now offline`

And all options on the menu of connection are disabled. I used a lot of commands to fix this problem, but none worked..

What I should do to fix this?

Comment: What commands did you try?

Comment: @OrganicMarble  Many commands like: 
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
then another one:
uname -a
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
lsmod
cat /etc/network/interfaces
cat /etc/resolv.conf
route -n
ifconfig -a
and some others, my problem is that all options all disabled I can't change any of those?

Comment: If you have a network cable then connect your computer to your modem and resume updating. If this doesn't work show your /etc/network/interfaces, /etc/resolv.conf and the output of the command ifconfig.

Comment: @wie5Ooma Ya I resume updating, but still I'm having  problems with Ethernet Network. I tried like it's said in this link: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2237078 but linux-image-generic_3.13.0.32.38_amd64.deb  its not found and only "Enable Neworking" field is now enable. any idea?

Comment: So, what's your problem now? Do you have a connection or not? The kernel file you mention has nothing to do with your connectivity

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem now (a year later) with Ubuntu 16.04 but I thought my answer may help someone else.
For me, I restarted my computer in Recovery Mode. From the recovery menu, I chose "network" --> Enable networking. After that, I get back to the main recovery menu and choose "resume" --> Resume normal boot.

It worked!